# Designing a caching schema for Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, caching, singleton

I have a Winform application that I am trying to implement caching in order to speed up the process of reading data everytime one of my class methods get called. I am thinking of using a Singleton-like approach. I am thinking of something like this:

```
public class MyCache {
    private MyDataClass _cacheData;
    private static MyCache _cache;

    public static MyCache CreateCache()
    {
        return _cache ?? new MyCache();
    }

    public void CacheData(MyDataClass data)
    {
        _cache = data;
    }

    public MyDataClass GetCache()
    {
        return _cache;
    } 
}
```

Can someone tell me if this approach is good or if there is a better approach I should use?

Comment: Depends on what you are caching...

Comment: Neolisk - Its data from a database.

Comment: You need to elaborate on which data from a database, how it's being used etc. Without more information, it's hard to say anything. You are asking for abstract caching for an abstract form, working against an abstract database. It's like prototyping a spherical horse in vacuum.

Comment: Neolisk - Okay. My application has 7 tables. They reside in a SQLite database. The main table is called Part. Part holds most of the data with foreign keys to a Vendor table, a Location table and a Manufacturing table. I have a data layer that communicated with SQLite and the tables via ADO.NET. Its a pretty simple and standard data layer with properties and a collection class. The foreign key tables are read only and are used to populate a Combobox. These comboboxes are what I want to cache. The data layer is separate from my UI (like it should be).

Comment: So every `ComboBox` is being populated from a single table?

Comment: Neolisk - Yes, each ComboBox is being data bound to a single table. So ComboBox1 is bound to my Vendor table. ComboBox 2 is bound to my Manufacturing table. ComboBox 3 is bound to my Location table.

Comment: Good - we are getting there... Is it conditional or always the same list? Meaning during the same user session, can the contents of dropdown change?

Comment: Neolisk - No. The contents never or rarely change. Its safe to assume the data getting binded to the ComboBoxes are fixed data.

Comment: Then you probably don't need caching at all. Did you notice any performance issue to make you concerned?

Comment: Not really, but my test database only has about 3 entries per table in it. On production, each of these tables has about 75 entries per table. That's about 225 rows that its loading every single time someone adds a record. I just assumed that it could be optimized a little by using some kind of caching structure.

Comment: 225 rows is not much, even if to be loaded with addition of each record. But if you want to optimize, I suggest a form level caching, i.e. shared/static lists with corresponding properties. Inside each property, if `Nothing`, populate from database, then read from _variable, so it will only load once. If you need code sample - let me know.

Comment: Neolisk - Thanks for the help. If you convert your comment into an answer, I'll accept your answer! Thanks again!

Comment: And thank you as well for cooperation - it's a pleasure dealing with someone who knows what they are doing. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your situation, I would suggest form-level caching, i.e. shared/static lists with corresponding properties. By lists I mean any type of object, but most likely it will be a dictionary - to have a `(key,value)` pair. Inside each property, if `Nothing`, populate from database, then read from `_variable`, so it will only load once. Something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> _VendorData;
public object VendorData
{
  get
  {
    if (_VendorData == null)
      _VendorData = GetVendorDictionary();
    return _VendorData;
  }
}

public Dictionary<string, string> GetVendorDictionary()
{
  //get vendor data from database and populate a dictionary
}
```

If you plan to have more objects in your cache, you might look into creating a `Dictionary` of `<YourObjectTypesEnum, Dictionary<String, String>>` instead, where `YourObjectTypesEnum` can be `Vendor`, `Manufacturing`, `Location` etc. So you get strict typing in your code, rather than accessing by `String`. Then you would test `ContainsKey` instead of null check and `.Add` to dictionary if missing.

If you later decide to use this cache on other forms, you can easily move it to a separate class, because all methods and properties are static anyway.